# Acquiring file icon makes JPanels disappear?

Tags: java, swing, filesystems, icons, jpanel

So recently I've started learning some Java , I've had experience in other languages (mostly web oriented ones like PHP , HTML etc. ) . So I started with some small project to like simple launcher / desktop overlay. Based on `JPanel` and here it started to get problematic .

I wanted to achieve something like windows 7 task-bar with applications that I can pin onto. So  I started to look around for way to look for "extracting" icon from exe file into Java. Found some topic on this site most of the answers is just URL to [this site](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html).

All of these work but the problem is , when I call for these functions (like `getSystemIcon`) it makes all panels above (parents ) disappear.  I can get all of them back by repainting , but is there another solution to that or I'm just doing something wrong?

### Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;


public class Startbar extends JPanel{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Config cfg = new Config();
public Startbar() {
    
    
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cfg.Resx,35));
    setBounds(0,1015,cfg.Resx,35);
    setVisible(true);
   
    this.setLayout(null);
    StartbarClock clock = new StartbarClock();
    clock.setBounds(cfg.Resx-135,0, 135, 35);
    this.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    
    
    add(clock);
    AddPins();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, cfg.Resx, 35);
    repaint();
}
public void AddPins(){
    String filename = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/Skype.exe";
    
    Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(filename));
    System.out.println(ico.getIconHeight());
        
    }
}
```

EDIT :
After adding timeout of 1 sec to the function everything works as it should ... wtf ?
Some code :

```
public class Startbar extends JPanel{
        
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                pin();
              }
        };
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000 ,listener);
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        Config cfg = new Config();
        public Startbar() {
            
            
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cfg.Resx,35));
            setBounds(0,1015,cfg.Resx,35);
            setVisible(true);
            setBackground(Color.black);
            this.setLayout(null);
            StartbarClock clock = new StartbarClock();
            
            add(clock);
            
            timer.start();
            //pin();
        }
        
        public void pin(){
            String filename = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone/Skype.exe";
            FileSystemView view = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();    
            Icon icon = view.getSystemIcon(new File(filename));
            System.out.println(icon.getIconHeight());
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't call repaint in paintComponet, you'll end up in a paint loop

Comment: *"started learning some JAVA"* Please learn that it is 'Java'.  No need to SHOUT it from the roof-tops.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: user992484 After putting that repaint() this panel becomes visible , otherwise it disappears like other ones .

Comment: Repaint will cause paintComponet to be called again & again. Your program will nose dive not a pool of resource hogging. Do yourself the favor and read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html then read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Comment: I think `repaint()` in `paintComponent()` is causing the problem as user992484 said. This is an obvious endless recursion. You may see the source of `Repaint` in `Component` to find that its true. Or you can simply put a `print` in `paintComponent()` to see what happens.

Comment: No it's not causing the problem , it was my idea for solution (before problem occured there was no repaint() in paint component ) .

Comment: setBounds(0,1015,cfg.Resx,35); is screwing with you, unless you have a window whose height is at least 1015 pixels + 35 in height....

Comment: Look, basically, the lack of any layout managers is screwing you over.  Take the time to understand the paint subsystem in swing and you will find it easier (and more fun) to produce the results youre after

Comment: Okay i figured out what's going on - If i call AddPins function with timer at 1 second (basically just timeout ) everything is okay , any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: @ the end of the pin method, add invalidate(), repaint() & let me know the results, or try & resize the window

Comment: Sorry, that should be repaint() only (3am with a crying baby does little for ones brain).  Invalidate will cause the parent container to re-layout its children, overriding the bounds you have set

Comment: Here's a thought. A call to getIcon is probably setting up a change reaction within paint subsystem which is causing a repaint request to be sent to the event dispatching thread. The way you have set your bounds will cause a subtle side effect, painting your panel @ 0x1015, which is probably beyond the visual bounds of your parent container. A call to invalidate will probably fix the problem.  The timer is probably allowing time for the ETD to complete its run (including laying out the parent container) before the icon loads. This is probably down to the way the icon image is physically loaded

Answer (score 3):

For what you are trying to do, set StartBar's background to black, then you don't need to overwrite paintComponet.

Don't set StartBar's bounds, use set/getPreferredSize instead.  This will allow the parent container the oppurtunity to calculate the best size for the component (which might explain your problem)

You seriously should conisder the use of layout managers.

I'd have two child panels (content & task).  I'd place all the application icons in the content, probably with a flow layout & the clock as/in the task, again, probably using a flow layout.  Then I'd use either a grid bag layout or a border layout to add them to the task bar panel.

It might not seem like it, but ts going to make your life so much easier in the long run

**UPDATE**

Okay, then please explain to me why mine works then:

And look, no need to override paintComponent or repaint in sight.

```
public class TaskBarPane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form TaskBarPane
     */
    public TaskBarPane() {
        
        initComponents();
        
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 24));
        
        pinTask(new File("C:/Program Files/BabyCounter/BabyCounter x64.exe"));
        
    }
    
    protected void pinTask(File task) {
        
        pnlContent.add(new TaskPane(task));
        
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        pnlContent = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pnlClock = new test.ClockPane();

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        pnlContent.setOpaque(false);
        java.awt.FlowLayout flowLayout1 = new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT);
        flowLayout1.setAlignOnBaseline(true);
        pnlContent.setLayout(flowLayout1);
        add(pnlContent, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pnlClock.setOpaque(false);
        add(pnlClock, java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST);
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private test.ClockPane pnlClock;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pnlContent;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

..

```
public class ClockPane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form ClockPane
     */
    public ClockPane() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Hello World");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 100;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);
        add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints);
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

..

```
public class TaskPane extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form TaskPane
     */
    public TaskPane() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public TaskPane(File task) {

        this();

        Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(task);
        lblIcon.setIcon(ico);

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        lblIcon = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        lblIcon.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblIcon.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblIcon.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        add(lblIcon, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());
    }// </editor-fold>
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblIcon;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

...

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TestFrame
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        pnlTaskBar = new test.TaskBarPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(pnlTaskBar, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private test.TaskBarPane pnlTaskBar;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

It took me 10 mins to put together (had to feed my 11 week old daughter, sorry)

Comment: Thanks for idea's and tips , it will come really handy ... but it's not solution for my problem here . Thanks for effort.

Comment: I dont think you read my question carefully ... my code works (even if its not as cool as yours , and I've removed repaint ) but the thing is  when i use "Icon ico = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File(filename));" all panels disappear .

Comment: And you're not listening.  Getting the icon is not the problem. You lack of understanding over swing in general is.  Bounds are relative to the parent, saying setBounds(0,1015,cfg.Resx,35) is saying, within my parent put me 1015 pixels from it's top edge.  This is going to cause your panel to "disappear" within it's parent component, unless it is 1015 + 35 pixels high. The fact that it appears that getting the icon is causing an issue in you code is simply coincidence, once you exit this point, the paint subsystem updates your dispay & it appears that your components disappear

Comment: But how large is the parent container? If the parent is only 100 pixels high, then this is a problem

Comment: Parent container is maximized to fullscreen .

Answer (score 0):

I added System.out.println("inRepaint") into your paintComponent method and ran the code...

```
16
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
inRepaint
...
```

My CPU usage ramped up to 85% before I killed it.

When I took it out, I got 4-5 as I resized the window with a cpu of around 7% before it went back to 1%

So, yeah, your code broke.

Comment: Okay I get this , repaint in paintComponent - fail .. but that wasn't my question.